# Difference AM-PM or PM-AM for a paired T-Test - to test if the mean of the differences = 0?

Tags: r, paired-data

I have a paired set of data, that I wish to perform a t test on to test if the mean of the differences is equal to 0. I notice there is a difference between if I do AM-PM vs PM-AM - which way should it be?:

```
AM = c(1,5,4,2,6,6, 7, 11,5,3,4,5,8,3,4,5,7,7,4,5)
PM = c(4,5,5,8,9,10,12,15,4,8,6,6,9,5,9,8,7,8,7,6)
data.frame(AM,PM,row.names=paste("Student",1:20))
```

What is the difference between:

```
d = PM-AM
```

and

```
d=AM-PM

t.test(d, mu=0, alternative="greater")
```

I've done both and they give me different p-values. Could someone explain to me what the differences are? And which one is the correct one to use? The output I get from the two respectively is:

```
    One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 5.5917, df = 19, p-value = 1.079e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.692384      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
     2.45
```

&

```
              One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = -5.5917, df = 19, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.207616       Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    -2.45
```

Comment: The two tests are the two sides of the same coin. The two $p$-values add up to $1$. The $t$-distribution is symmetric, so the probability of getting a $t$-value of $5.5917$ or *greater* is `pt(5.5917, 19, lower=FALSE)` but this is the same as the probability of getting a $t$-value of $-5.5917$ or *smaller:* `pt(-5.5917, 19)`. In the second test, the $p$-value is the answer to the question "what is the probability of getting a $t$-value of $-5.5917$ or *greater* if the null hypothesis were true", which is: `pt(-5.5917, 19, lower=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In light of the edit to your question, the confusion appears to be over the specification of the alternative hypothesis. If you are just testing for whether the mean of the differences is not equal to $0$, i.e. $H_1:\mu_{d} \ne 0$ then you want to do:

`t.test(d,mu=0,alternative="two.sided")`

You will notice this gives identical results whether `d` is defined as `AM - PM` or `PM - AM`. If on the other hand you want your alternative hypothesis to specifically be that $H_1:\mu_{d} > 0$ or specifically that $H_1:\mu_{d} < 0$  then you will need to define `d` and set the `alternative` to be either `greater` or `less` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you are evaluating the hypothesis that AM is greater that PM, while indeed it is less. Just change the order of sets in function call:

```
t.test(PM,AM, paired=TRUE, alternative="greater")
```

or change the alternative:

```
t.test(AM,PM, paired=TRUE, alternative="less")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still not sure which way I should be doing it? AM-PM or PM-AM? To give you a bit of background, the question I am trying to answer is whether students have better attention in the morning or afternoon - not sure which. So my null hypothesis is that there is no difference in the population means i.e. $H_{0}:U_{d} = 0$ and the alternative is $H_{0}:U_{d} > 0$ - Which way would be correct to test this?

Comment: @mathstudent The null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis are complements of each other. So if the null hypothesis is $H_{0}:U_{d}=0$, the alternative is $H_{1}:U_{d}\neq 0$. This hypothesis is a two-sided hypothesis and can be checked by `t.test(PM,AM, paired=TRUE, alternative="two.sided")`.